# Audio element won't display/play inside iframe in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio, iframe

I have this snippet of HTML5, which allows the user to click and play a bit of audio:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="cell.ogg">
    <source src="cell.mp3">
    <source src="cell.m4a">
</audio>
```

This works fine in FF 8 on OS X Lion.  The audio player controls appear, I can click play, and it plays the ogg version.

But if I put the containing file inside the iframe of another HTML5 document (both from the local file system; no cross-origin issues), then it doesn't work.  The rest of the HTML displays fine, but Firefox acts as if it doesn't support any of the media formats.

Here's the function I use to add the page to the iframe:

```
function postContentToIframe(content)
{
    var iframe = $("#displayContents")[0].contentWindow.document;
    iframe.open(); iframe.close(); // must open and close document object to start using it!
    $("body", iframe).append(content).hide().fadeIn("slow");
    return;
}
```

Here's how FF renders it.

[image]

Why?  And how do I fix it?  TIA.

Comment: New info: Hosted the files on Apache (cause Chrome has cross-origin issues with local files).  Tested with Chrome 16.  Same exact issue!  The audio plays when rendered as it own page but not when in the iframe.  Weird.

Comment: I wonder if it's a security-related issue. Are you getting any error reports in the console?

Comment: I'm doing some logging, which shows up in the console, but no errors in FF or Chrome.

Comment: New info: If I delete the JS function and manually add the source in the iframe (<iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>), the audio works fine.  So, the problem must be with how the JS function adds the content.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved.  It was a directory/relative URL issue.  The base HTML file (with the iframe element) was in a different directory from the appended HTML file (the iframe contents) and the audio files.  Thus it couldn't find the audio files.

Solution:  Either put all files into one directory, or (better) use absolue URLs instead of relative URLs.